# Missing "from" in JPA correlated subquery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, correlated-subquery

I'm struggling with JPA Criteria API subquery correlation. From a complex query, I replicated my issue with this simple case:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @ManyToMany
    Set<Person> relatives;

}
```

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<Person> from = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);

Subquery<Long> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);

SetJoin<Person, Person> correlate = subquery.correlate(from.joinSet("relatives"));

Subquery<Long> where = subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(correlate)).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(correlate.get("name"), "Giovanni"));

criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(from)).where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(where, 0L));

entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Which fails generating a subquery with an empty `from ...` clause:

```
select count(generatedAlias0)
from Person as generatedAlias0
inner join generatedAlias0.relatives as generatedAlias1
where (
    select count(generatedAlias1)
    from
    where generatedAlias1.name=:param0
) > 0L
```

I thought that `correlate` will set the correct `from`. What am I missing?

Comment: If this is with the latest version, you should file a bug report. Even if there was a problem with the parameters you use, it should still either try to correct it or throw an exception, but never generate invalid syntax.

Comment: It throws an "unexpected token" exception, so I don't think it's a bug. I'm on the the latest Hibernate and this seems to me a rather simple query, so I rather think I'm doing something wrong with the correlation…

Answer (score 1):

I'll fixed this: problem was the wrong expression used as `correlate` argument. The correlation should be done on the *originating* `From` expression, not the target; i.e.

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<Person> from = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);

Subquery<Long> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);

Root<Person> correlate = subquery.correlate(from);
// Instead of SetJoin<Person, Person> correlate = subquery.correlate(from.joinSet("relatives"));

Subquery<Long> where = subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(correlate)).where(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(correlate.joinSet("relatives").get("name"), "Giovanni")
                          /* ^^^ instead of correlate.get("name") */
);

criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(from)).where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(where, 0L));

entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
```